# Cannot delete my Area 51 account because of site design

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-accounts

After thinking about it, I'm trying to delete my Area 51 account. (Sure, some of the proposed sites are interesting, but it's not really worth the hassle to me right now, and I find having "unnecessary" sites kind of distracting.)

Naturally, having had experience with deleting sites before, I went to the "contact us" link to fill out a deletion form. But on Area 51 (and, I suppose, not on other sites), [the "contact us" link](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) is apparently associated with the meta site. As a result, after I filled out my deletion form, I received a notification that

> this operation cannot be performed on a meta site; please continue on the main site

But the "contact us" page for the main site is the same one as that of the meta site, and moreover is hosted on the meta section of the site. I *can't* "continue on the main site", and it's thus impossible to delete my account.